# rails test database cloning dev database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and following Michael Hartls Ruby on Rails Tutorial. When I run bundle rake exec test, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", SessionsControllerTest, 2.331314]
test_should_get_new#SessionsControllerTest (2.33s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could    not find table 'users'
```

and once similar for all of my tests.  I see that my test database: test.sqlite3 is empty.  My development database development.sqlite3 does have the users table in it.

I tried running the following to attempt cloning the users database to the test database, but nothing is working:

```
rake db:migrate:reset
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare

rake db:test:clone

rake db:test:prepare
rake db:test:load
```

but it's still empty.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you  post your config/database.yml

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to get it with:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Give it a try, I've had this problem before myself. I believe that

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

is deprecated. What version of ruby and rails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a fix, although I'm still not sure why there was a problem to begin with.  What I did was I took the pure Sql CREATE TABLE used to create the development table and executed it in the users table.  Now everything is working fine.